# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte - AES.MODE_EAX Encryption - Pycryptodome

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, utf-8, aes, pycryptodome

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt values, using python `pycryptodome`, saved to my Postgresql database on the client side based on example 2 found here; [SymmetricEncryptionClientSide](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/SymmetricEncryptionClientSide#example-two---use-typedecorator). However, I keep running into UnicodeDecodeErrors, such as the following one;

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte`

This is my code;

```
nonce = uuid.uuid4().bytes
str_key = "wq5RdHHfzCW1/2eE" # example key

def sym_encrypt(data):
    key = str_key.encode("utf-8")
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce=nonce)
    data = data + (" " * (16 - (len(data) % 16)))
    return cipher.encrypt(data.encode("utf-8")).hex()


def sym_decrypt(data):
    key = str_key.encode("utf-8")
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce=nonce)
    return cipher.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(data)).decode("utf8").rstrip()
```

`nounce` is used to ensure that all the same values have the same encryption string for querying purposes. It's the same reason why the values get Hex.

When performing the encryption on a `string` value such as; `test@test.com` using the encryption function above I get the following string saved to my database;
`938174e09f8411a4957b7b91e07162b4` which is a `string`

However, when I perform the decrypt part as shown above I get the `UnicodeDecodeError` error.

For more information;

this is what the value looks like after encoding and before encryption and hex:

`b'test@test.com   '`

This is what the value looks like after encoding and encryption and before hex:

`b'\x92\xa1\xe1\x06\xd1\xd8\x8c\xbdv0\xb2\x13p!$#'`

When encoding the value before decryption the value looks like:

`b'938174e09f8411a4957b7b91e07162b4'`

But after unhexlify the value the byte looks different to the byte after encryption:

`b'\x93\x81t\xe0\x9f\x84\x11\xa4\x95{{\x91\xe0qb\xb4'`

I'm not sure what is happening here. I expected the byte to look the same after encryption and when unhexlify, but this is not the case. When I perform the decrypt I get the '`UnicodeDecodeError` error.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran your code with added imports and code to actually call encrypt/decrypt and it worked correctly.  make a [mcve] that reproduces the issue that can be copied and run without additional changes.  the problem is in code not shown.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen. You were right, the issue was not related to the encryption/decryption, but rather with my database field and the TypeDecorator I was using.